# One Youtube Video will not load in Fancybox but others will.

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, fancybox-2

I have one video out of several that will not load in a fancy box. 
The url for the video that I am having troubles with is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msVNbasvAic

Javascript (I pulled from another SO entry)

```
$("a.fancyvideo").click(function() {
$.fancybox({
        'padding'       : 0,
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'title'         : this.title,
        'width'     : 680,
        'height'        : 495,
        'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
        'type'          : 'swf',
        'swf'           : {
             'wmode'        : 'transparent',
            'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
        }
    });

return false;
});
```

HTML
(this one works)

```
<a class="fancyvideo"href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8oCliTpqk4">Soft close drawer glide system installation</a>
```

(this one don't)

```
<a class="fancyvideo" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msVNbasvAic">Soft close door attachment installation</a>
```

I think there may be some issue with the video, because sometimes it won't even load when you click the YouTube link in the Fancybox window.  It does load that way most the time though.  I have not been able to get it to play in a Fancybox window no matter what, even using different scripts that I have found and even running on jsfiddle.  Any thoughts?

Comment: even on youtube, this video doesn't work for me

Comment: if the video has issues (it sends a [player error](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3037019?p=player_error1&rd=1) ), not fancybox or any other modal window will be able to open it. It's a localized issue and not fancybox issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's a particular isolated issue.

Comment: OK thanks for the info. Like I said 90+% of the time it would play on you tube but it would never play in the fancybox window.  I'll just chalk it up to a bad video. I would remove this question if I could.  Sorry for the trouble.